# How can i get a date with yyyy_mm_dd format from a datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

i have 2 datepickers, both of them have the same structuture. The only difference is their name. One has id="fecha_1_1" and the other one id="fecha_1_2"

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <p>Desde</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-line">
            <input id="fecha_1_2" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="Seleccione una fecha de inicio" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i detect if one of them changes with this sentence:

```
 $('#fecha_1_2, #fecha_1_1').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker().on('dateSelected', function (e, date)
```

the problem is that i need to access to the date of the one that didn´t triggered the ajax sentence, and with $(fecha_x_x).val() i get a date with the format day, dd mm yyyy and i need it with yyyy_mm_dd format

Comment: _"with this ajax sentence"_ - there is nothing "AJAX" about that line. _"the problem is that i need to access to the date of the one that didn´t triggered the ajax sentence"_ - so store that one into a variable at the point that one triggers its `dateSelected` event then - then you can access it via that variable at any later point.

Comment: and how can i access to the values of month year and day? That´s the problem for me, because i can access to the date with .val(), but i get it with a format that i cant use

Comment: You are not supposed to read it via `.val` in the first place. The `change` event callback function gets a date instance passed in as second parameter already, https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker#events

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it in pure Javascript you can use **toISOString()** that would give you something like this: **2021-07-02T13:06:53.422Z (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss sss)**
, or you try it with **moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');**

Comment: With toISOString() i get "toISOString is not a function", because i think .val() doesn´t return a date type